# How to install OS on HP iLO using Ansible or Terraform?

Tags: ansible, terraform

I have a Ubuntu image on my pc.
I want to install this OS on a server using HP iLO. How do I use Ansible or Terraform to automate the installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72457355/), without information it is not possible to provide much or good guidance.

Ansible has already a lot of modules for communication with Remote Management Cards and chips (RMC) available. You may start with getting familar in [how to connect to HP iLO interface and gather information](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/hpilo_info_module.html), followed by [boot system using specific media through HP iLO interface](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/hpilo_boot_module.html).

The necessary modules, `hpilo_info module` and `hpilo_boot module` are from [Collections in the Community Namespace » Community.General](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/index.html).

In the documentaton are [Examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/hpilo_boot_module.html#examples) for how to remote boot the server

```yaml
- name: Boot from ISO image
  hpilo_boot:
    host: "{{ SERVER }}"
    login: "{{ USER }}"
    password: "{{ PASSWORD }}"
    media: cdrom
    image: http://share_on_myPC/ubuntu.iso
```

**Further Links**

- [Ansible Galaxy HP iLO](https://galaxy.ansible.com/hpe/ilo)
- [iLO REST Role](https://github.com/HewlettPackard/ansible-ilorest-role)